# What happens to a Giant Toad with a Lightning Staff?

Tags: dnd-4e, summoning

If I'm playing a druid who has taken a Lightning  Staff for Mark of Storm cheese, and I summon a giant toad, is its tongue electrified such that I can benefit from mark of storm from its attacks?

Comment: "The same thing that happens to anyone else." Ororo, genasi sorceress.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

Summon Giant Toad is an implement power, and the standard action attack does not have keywords of it's own so it inherits them. You are channeling your control of the toad through the staff and all damage from the toad is lightning damage.

Comment: You don't control the toad, [the toad controls you](http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/201/5/2/All_hail_the_hypnotoad____by_elnano93.gif).